# Ошибка: ionic не установлен

Tags: android, framework, ionic

Скачал *ionic framwork*, он у меня работал, всё было хорошо. На следующий день я включаю ноутбук, пишу в консоли `ionic start <AppName> blank`, и выдает ошибку, типа «ionic не установлен».

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ npm install -g ionic
```

или

```
$ ionic -v
```

чтобы узнать текущую установленную версию

Если дело на винде, то надо еще путь к npm в системные переменные добавить
PATH: C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\npm